# Is DialogApi1.1 supported in Excel 2013 and 2016 (manifest requirements)

Tags: office-js, office-store

According to Microsoft online documentation located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability), DialogApi 1.1 seems to supported in both Excel 2013 and 2016,  however, when running our manifest it through the validation tool [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-addin-validator), it does not include them as supported platforms (even though Excel Online, Mac and iPad is included):

- Excel for iPad
- Excel 2016 for Mac
- Excel Online
- Word for iPad
- Word 2016 for Mac
- Word Online
- Word 2013 Service Pack 1 or later
- Word 2016 or later
- PowerPoint for iPad
- PowerPoint 2016 for Mac
- PowerPoint Online
- PowerPoint 2013 Service Pack 1 or later
- PowerPoint 2016 or later

If we remove the "DialogApi" node from the manifest (sample below), it does include Excel 2013 and 2016 in the supported platforms.

```
<Hosts>
  <Host Name="Document" />
  <Host Name="Presentation" />
  <Host Name="Workbook" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
     <Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

- Excel for iPad
- Excel 2016 for Mac
- ***Excel 2013 or later***
- ***Excel 2016 or later***
- Excel Online
- Word for iPad
- Word 2016 for Mac
- Word Online
- Word 2013 or later
- Word 2016 or later
- PowerPoint for iPad
- PowerPoint 2016 for Mac
- PowerPoint Online
- PowerPoint 2013 or later
- PowerPoint 2016 or later

There seems to be a discrepancy between the documentation and validation tool.  We learned this the hard way as the store also did not approve our add-in for Excel 2016, even though when side-loading it, it passed QA perfectly.

Can someone from Microsoft please confirm or point us to what we might be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't follow. The list you're reporting the validation tool returns `Word 2013 Service Pack 1 or later`.

Comment: Hi Marc - I'm talking about Excel, not Word in this case.  "Excel 2016 or later" seems to be only supported when we exclude the "DialogApi1.1" requirement. Please let me know if this is not clear.